# Why tomcat does'nt work with proxy set in a network with netbeans(8.2)?

Tags: apache, tomcat, netbeans, server, netbeans-8

so i have been working on apache tomcat in netbeans and i faced one issue due to which tomcat was not starting in my organization's network, but with same settings it was running perfectly on my home wifi.

Later, i figured out if i set proxy to "No proxy" in the netbeans settings it will work and the solution worked. But, i still do not understand why this happened.

I researched a little but answers were not satisfactory. Basically, i want to understand how apache tomcat startup was affected and in what cases i may need a proxy.

You can consider me as a beginner if you are answering to this... Thanks!